# Facebook social plugin image configure

Tags: plugins, facebook-social-plugins

I set a like button in facebook social plugin to enable user to share my web through facebook. It was success but there is a small image which captured a small part of my web. I cannot configure which part of website it captured. Is there any solution for me to control the image display?![photo for reference][1]

photo link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvaq.png